# how to upload mp3 file using asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to upload mp3 file using file uploader and I don't want to save it in the database I used server.mappath

```
if (FileUploadsong.HasFiles)
    {
      FileUploadsong.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("songs" + "/" + Txtsongname + "~/mp3file/"));
        byte[] mp3file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("songs");
    }
```

but I got this error:

[image: path error]

Answer (score 4):

The error tells you that you path name is invalid and cannot be found.
That is, because you are using the control itself as part of your path, instead of its `.Text` property:

```
if (FileUploadsong.HasFiles)
{
    FileUploadsong.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("songs" + "/" + Txtsongname.Text + "/mp3file/"));
    byte[] mp3file = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("songs");
}
```

And please, post your errors as text, not as an image. Screenreaders cannot interpret images and if the image does get deleted, so does your error message for everyone.